# Woocommerce: getting customer e-mail when hooking into 'applied coupon' action

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, mailchimp

I found there is an action called `woocommerce_applied_coupon` that passes the coupon code [down to the](https://cmsdk.com/php/woocommerce-action-on-specific-coupon-code-applied-prior-to-order-submission.html) hook you write.

But, my use-case is this: I want to update a tag on the mailchimp-subscriber information on certain coupons being used. That way, we prevent sending e-mails reminding customers about the coupon if they already used it.

Is there a way to get the customer information when hooking into the `woocommerce_applied_coupon` action so I know which contact to update?

Comment: At this stage, I don't think that this hook provides any data that contains user information, but you can get current logged-in user info, does it work for you?

Comment: Hi @Amin. Do you mean the wordpress user when you say 'user'? In that case that will not help me. I would need the user logged into the webshop, not the CMS.

Comment: What do you mean by webshop? WordPress has only one user management system which is shared in all parts of the website

Comment: Well I found the answer. You need to hook into `woocommerce_checkout_order_processed` and use `$order->get_items('coupon')` on the order object. The subscriber (if any) can be found in `$order->get_data()['billing']['email']`